# how to get my if statement working correctly, response code always show 1 and never gets out of the loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to check if an application has been restarted successfully, I have no issue with stopping the application but having issues with starting the app. The app starts but the script continues to run and never gets out of the loop when the site is back up.

I have a var `$aem_curl` this runs another script and displays the following result if it successful
`CheckHttp OK: 200, found /crxde/ in 11038 bytes` and gives a response code of `0`. But if it fails it displays `CheckHttp CRITICAL: 503` and response code of `2`

My code:

```
aem_curl="./check-http-aem.rb -h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 30"
STOP_TMOUT=15
echo "starting $AEM_APP this will take a few mins..." | ${LOG_FILE}
    sudo $restart_aem start
    count=0
    while true; do
      echo "Waiting for AEM to start try #${count} ..." | ${LOG_FILE}

        $aem_curl

     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "AEM has started! status code - $?" | ${LOG_FILE} && break
     else
        echo "AEM has not started yet - status code is $?" | ${LOG_FILE}
     fi
      if [ "$count" -eq "${STOP_TMOUT}" ]; then
              MESSAGE="Already waited 10 minutes for AEM start something is amiss." | ${LOG_FILE}
              exit 1
      fi
      count=$(($count+1))
      sleep 20
    done
```

My output:

```
Waiting for AEM to start try #0 ...
CheckHttp CRITICAL: Request error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:4502 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 4502)
AEM has not started yet - status code is 1
Waiting for AEM to start try #1 ...
CheckHttp CRITICAL: 503
AEM has not started yet - status code is 1
Waiting for AEM to start try #2 ...
CheckHttp CRITICAL: 503
...
Waiting for AEM to start try #19 ...
CheckHttp CRITICAL: 200, did not find /'crxde'/ in 11038 bytes: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/><title>CRXDE Lite</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/crxde_favicon.ico"><link type="image/...
AEM has not started yet - status code is 1
Waiting for AEM to start try #20 ...
CheckHttp CRITICAL: 200, did not find /'crxde'/ in 11038 bytes: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/><title>CRXDE Lite</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/crxde_favicon.ico"><link type="image/...
AEM has not started yet - status code is 1
```

Comment: What is `${LOG_FILE}`? in particular is it a process - or a file? Why are you `break`ing *conditionally* depending on whether `echo ... | ${LOG_FILE}` succeeds?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Don't store commands in variables; they're for data, not executable code use a function (that's what they're for) or possibly an array. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) (but ignore all suggestions involving `eval` -- it's a massive bug magnet).

Comment: `LOG_FILE` is just the file where to log the restart output
`LOG_FILE="tee -a ${LOG_LOC}/aem-restart.log.${CURRENTDATE}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```bsh
maxcount=15
count=0
while [ "$count" -lt "$maxcount" ] && ! ./check-http-aem.rb -h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 30; do
 ...
 sleep 20
 let count+=1
done

if [ "$count" -eq "$maxcount" ] ; then
  echo "AEM hasn't started" >/dev/stderr
  exit 1
fi
```

The while loop will run until either $count > $maxcount **OR** `./check-http-aem.rb` returns an exit code of 0 (true)

BTW, I have no idea what your `$LOG_FILE` variable is or why you're piping text into it sometimes but setting "$MESSAGE" another time.  Or why you're not using a shell function instead of a variable.  Or an existing tool like `logger`.  It's not really relevant to the question so I'll just pretend it prints something to stderr and ignore it.

---

Also...

It's better to use an array to hold command arguments than to rely on the shell to split a scalar variable on whitespace.  For example, do this:

```bsh
aem_args=(-h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 3)
./check-http-aem.rb "${aem_args[@]}"
```

or

```bsh
aem_curl=./check-http-aem.rb
aem_args=(-h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 3)
$aem_curl "${aem_args[@]}"
```

instead of:

```
aem_curl="./check-http-aem.rb -h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 30"
$aem_curl
```

These all do essentially the same thing, but it's far easier to make mistakes and get unexpected behaviour with the latter.  You can't, for example, use the latter form to easily pass an argument to your script that contains a space character, not without changing the IFS variable, which will have other, probably unwanted, consequences.  But using an array, it's trivial to do that.

In other words, you could do this:

```bsh
maxcount=15
count=0
aem_args=(-h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 3)

while [ "$count" -lt "$maxcount" ] && ! ./check-http-aem.rb "${aem_args[@]}"; do
 ...
 sleep 20
 let count+=1
done
```

Comment: I added your suggestion but it looks like it just starts the app right away in the first while loop. But the app is still not up.

output:
```starting Adobe AEM 6.5 AUTHOR mode this will take a few mins...
Starting Adobe AEM 6.5 - author mode
CheckHttp CRITICAL: Request error: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:4502 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 4502)
Waiting for AEM to start try #0 ...
AEM has started! status code - 0```

Comment: Are you sure that your check-http-aem.rb script exits with 0 on success, non-zero on errors?

Comment: I got it working the issue was my curl command had single quotes in `crxde` after removing the single quotes it was able to break from the loop

`aem_args=(-h localhost -P 4502 -p /crx/de/index.jsp --response-code 200 -q 'crxde' -t 3)`

Comment: Thanks for your help @cas